# Как в явном виде указать корневую директорию проекта для webpack и gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp, webpack

У меня `gulpfile.js` и `package.json` находятся в корневой директории проекта, но сами gulp-таски - нет:

Корневая директория проекта

gulpfile.js

some_folder

gulp_tasks

task1.js

task2.js

webpack.js

Для загрузки тасков, я использую такую функцию:

```
function LazyRequireTask(taskName, path, options) {   

    options = options || {};

    options.taskName = taskName;
    gulp.task(taskName, function(callback){
        let task = require(path).call(this, options);
        return task(callback);
    });
}
```

Пример загрузки таска:

```
LazyRequireTask('pug to html', 'some_folder/gulp_tasks/pug2html.js');
```

`Webpack` является одним из gulp-тасков. `Webpack` и другие gulp-таски принимают
`some_folder/gulp_tasks/` за корневую директорию проекта, и это порождает ряд проблем, но я хочу сохранить такую организацию тасков. Как я могу в явном виде указать корневую директорию проекта для всех gulp-тасков? (В случае с webpack `webpack` это будет по-другому).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял вам необходимо в тасках получить путь к каталогу  где выполняеться запуск gulp файла

1. Это можно сделать через process.cwd() - вернет текущую рабочую дерикторию
2. Можно передать явно console environment variable и уже в process.evn.[var_name] получить нужные данные

Пример:
`PATH='/path/your/project' gulp [task_name]` и во всех тасках у вас будет доступна `process.evn.PATH`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Первый способ вполне хороший: по сути всё, что надо сделать - это передать `process.cwd() ` в таск через `options`. Всё просто, оказывается!

Comment: process.cwd() можно использовать в самом таске будет тот же путь что и в gulp файле